# xsl:for-each does not loop inner elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

XML

```
    <authors>
        <author url="http://dl.acm.org/">Chung-Hwan Lim</author>
        <author url="http://dl.acm.org/">Seog Park</author>
        <author url="http://dl.acm.org/">Sang H. Son</author>
    </authors>
```

XSLT

```
<div class="authors">
    <xsl:for-each select="authors">
        <a style="vertical-align:middle">
            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                <xsl:value-of select="@url"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </a>
    </xsl:for-each>
</div>
```

O/P

```
   <div class="authors"><a style="vertical-align:middle" href="">
                Chung-Hwan Lim
                Seog Park
                Sang H. Son
            </a></div>
```

The problem is I'm expecting three `<a>` tags but I'm only getting one. Why is that? why doesn't the `xsl:for-each' loop inner elements? How can I fix this?

Comment: You have written `authors`, you probably meant `author`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're selecting every `authors` tag in your foreach. You should select `author` instead. Like  `<xsl:for-each select="authors/author">`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to process the `author` elements then you need `select="authors/author"`.